# Camera not being enabled when program is run

Tags: pi-4, camera, gstreamer

I am trying to use the raspberry pi to do object detection and identification with voice feedback. The program was working well but recently my sd card got corrupted and so I got a new one and installed a new operating system. After setting up my camera for the program i tried to run it and nothing happened. After some minutes I clicked ctrl+c and an error about the GStreamer shows up.

Code:

```
import cv2
import pyttsx3
import numpy as np

# Load the class names
classNames = []
classFile = "coco.names"
with open(classFile, "rt") as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip("\n").split("\n")

# Set up model configuration and weights paths
configPath = "ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt"
weightsPath = "frozen_inference_graph.pb"

# Initialize the neural network for object detection
net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath, configPath)
net.setInputSize(320, 320)
net.setInputScale(1.0 / 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

# Initialize text-to-speech engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()

# Dictionary to track the counts for each class
class_counts = {}

# Set to store detected classes
detected_classes = set()

# Video capture setup
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

# Function to detect objects
def getObjects(img, thres, nms, objects=[]):
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=thres, nmsThreshold=nms)

    if len(objects) == 0:
        objects = classNames

    objectInfo = []

    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), bbox):
            className = classNames[classId - 1]
            if className in objects:
                objectInfo.append([box, className])

                # Speak the detected class name
                engine.say(f"{className} detected")
                engine.runAndWait()

                # Draw a box and label on the image
                cv2.rectangle(img, box, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
                cv2.putText(img, className.upper(), (box[0] + 10, box[1] + 30),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.putText(img, str(round(confidence * 100, 2)), (box[0] + 200, box[1] + 30),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    return img, objectInfo

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    result, objectInfo = getObjects(img, 0.60, 0.2)
    cv2.imshow("Output", img)

    # Check for 'q' key press
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the video capture object and close the OpenCV window
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error I am getting:

```
(python:2889): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:57:30.230:
Trying to dispose element pipeline0, but it is in PAUSED instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.

[ WARN:0@29.986] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1356) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline

(python:2889): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:57:30.230:
Trying to dispose element videoconvert0, but it is in PLAYING instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.

[ WARN:0@29.987] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created

(python:2889): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:57:30.231:
Trying to dispose element appsink0, but it is in READY instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.
```

I never encountered this problem previously and i am still using the exact same pi and camera module that i was using so I was wondering if anyone could explain exactly what is causing this error

Comment: `i am still using the exact same pi and camera module` ... what about software, are you using the same software?`

Comment: Maybe the new SD card is corrupted. Because your setup worked well before your changed it.

Comment: Have you tried all the options to detect the camera as documented at: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html#introducing-the-raspberry-pi-cameras